# TScrollBox in ActiveX Form does not get mouse scroll

Tags: delphi, activex, c++builder, vcl

I have a generic VCL ActiveX Form with a TScrollBox on it.  The TScrollBox does not get the OnMouseWheel message when I insert the control into a container.  When I create the same control hierarchy in a normal VCL application, the TScrollBox does get the OnMouseWheel as expected.

Is there something special I have to do to receive mouse wheel messages in an ActiveX Form (C++ or Delphi) or does this just not work?

Comment: By default a scrollbox shouldn't receive a `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message (which OnMouseWheel event acts on), as the scrollbox does not receive focus. Only if you set 'tabstop' to true, and then navigate to the control with tabs. The box should be getting help in your VCL setup - it doesn't in XE2.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz  XE3 and higher the TScrollBox gets mouse wheel messages properly, unless its in an ActiveX Form apparently

Comment: @Gregor that's because the VCL redirects the messages and actually goes against the platform UI guidelines. Message should be handled by control with focus. VCL changes that to control under the cursor. It's a very messy area. Not at all surprising that ActiveX forms are different. Nasty things they are.